# The "Save site as template" option isn't available

Tags: templates, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

This is what the site settings look like for my SharePoint online site:

[image]

I don't see the option under "site actions" to "save site as template".

I have read online that publishing has to be turned on, or off? For this site, I turned it on yesterday, in the site collection features:

[image: SharePoint Server Publishing Active in site collection features]

and in the site features:

[image: SharePoint Server Publishing Active in site features]

I have created a new site without publishing ever turned on, and it has the same problem.

Comment: Are you an administrator of the SharePoint Online environment or just an owner of that site? Saving a site as a template is one of the features that get disabled by default due to custom scripts being disabled across the environment. https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

The Publishing feature must be disabled for the entire site collection, both at the Site Collection level and the Site level.

That feature is also not available for Modern sites and subsites of Modern sites.